# Reactjs update componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make an API call with `componentDidMount`. The code delivers me the results as the page renders. However, I don't seem to be able to update its values and pass it into ComponentDidMount. My code is below.

```
getInitialState: function(){
return {main: '', place: 'London, UK', weather: [{icon: ''}] }
},

componentDidMount: function(){
var comp = this;
$.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+comp.state.place+"&appid=abunchofnumbers", function(data){
comp.setState(data);
}); 
},

setit: function(){
this.setState({place: document.getElementById('stuff').value});
console.log(this.state.place);
},

render: function(){
return (<div>
<p>{this.state.name}</p>
<p>{this.state.main.temp}</p>
<p>{this.state.weather[0].icon}</p>
<input type="text" id="stuff" />
<input type="submit" value="submeet" onClick={this.setit}/>
</div>);
}
```

In addition, it takes two clicks to console.log the most recent entry in `place`. Clicking it only once returns the value it was before.

EDIT: The following adjustments have since been made to the code, and work as they should. However, when data is re-rendered, it has a strange flicker effect.

```
callthebase: function(){
var comp = this;
$.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+comp.state.place+"&appid=1333982caee02b04d765f15ec51bf10d", function(data){
comp.setState(data);
}); 
},

componentDidMount: function(){
return this.callthebase();
},

componentDidUpdate:function(){
return this.callthebase();
},

setit: function(){
this.setState({place: document.getElementById('stuff').value});
},

render: function(){
return (<div>
<p>{this.state.name}</p>
<p>{this.state.main.temp}</p>
<p>{this.state.weather[0].icon}</p>
<input type="text" id="stuff" />
<input type="submit" value="submeet" onClick={this.setit}/>
</div>);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to respond to a change in state, you should define a `componentDidUpdate` method and check if `place` changes. If it does, make a new request.

I recommend moving your `GET` request code out of `componentDidMount` and into a new function. Then call that function in `componentDidMount` and in `componentDidUpdate`.

Also, you shouldn't need to use `getElementById` in your component. Instead, you should pass `onChange` and `value` props to your input and store the input's value in your component's state.

See: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate

Comment: It works! Thanks! I do have one question though. When the component updates it has a strange flickering effect. What's the story there? Will update my question to show the updated code.

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing the flicker. I'm guessing something is causing additional re-renders. Here is how I would write what I think you're going for: http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/yJvPxy?editors=0010#0

Comment: Yes. There was additional re-renders happening. I believe that componentDidUpdate was running multiple times, possibly due to multiple events.